# Variable naming conventions other than trailing underscore

Tags: javascript, variables, jslint

I'm reformatting a plug-in so that it passes JSLint. Plug-in uses trailing underscores to name local variables, like so:

```
var __slice = [].slice,
    __indexOf = [].indexOf
```

JSLint does not like this. 
What's another easily recognisable convention for naming these, that JSLint won't object to?

Comment: Is this a plugin you wrote or not? If not, you should be excluding third party files from your linting process. If so, you could just remove the underscores?

Comment: I didn't write it originally, but I've modified it extensively enough  that it needs to be included in my code quality standards, which for this project means passing JSLint. The original is credited in the header per the requirements of the plug-in author.

Comment: These are leading underscores, not trailing underscores.

Comment: The "solution" of course, is to use a real linter, not one created by a cranky guy trying to impose his personal opinions on everyone. You will find either jshint or eslint a much better choice. For instance, they are much configurable. If this is a corporate policy issue, it is well worth the time to convince your management to switch to a good linter. Based on github start, npm has only 1/10 the popularity of either jshint or eslint. jscs may also be a possibility. But if you are stuck with jslint, did you look at the `nomen` option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from Douglas Crockford, the guy who invented JSLint:

> Do not use _ (underbar) as the first character of a name. It is
>   sometimes used to indicate privacy, but it does not actually provide
>   privacy. If privacy is important, use the forms that provide private
>   members. Avoid conventions that demonstrate a lack of competence.
>
> Most variables and functions should start with a lower case letter.

Taken from [Code Conventions for the JavaScript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) .

You can look at [Private Members in Javascript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) to see what he meant by `use the forms that provide private members.`

Comment: This isn't answering their question, they're asking for an alternative not for the reasons why it isn't allowed.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I think the alternative is present inside the quote: "Most variables and functions should start with a lower case letter."

Comment: That alternative does not satisfy the OP's requirement for an "easily recognisable convention".

Comment: could prefix the name: `privateBar = 'boo';`

I don't mind the underscore prefix myself...