# webstorm: what does "Element is not exported" warning mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, warnings, webstorm

if i write such code in webstorm

```
export class someOne {
  constructor(param) {
    this.test = param;
  }

  useTest(){
    return this.test;
  }
}


console.log(new someOne(123).useTest());
```

and mouseover on "this.test" i see the warning: "Element is not exported"

[image: element is not exported wtf]

what does it mean?
if i change the `.test` to `.test1` the warning disappears

Comment: If it works, and changing the variable name makes the warning go away -- I suspect it's a conflict with webstorm's understanding of variable names. I came across this with MongoDB function names triggering deprecation warnings for non-Mongo features

Comment: Weird error. I've gotten this too when exporting classes in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1.

Comment: Same here. PhpStorm 2016.1

Answer (score 9):

For me it worked to mark all "private" properties with a prefixed underscore. Obviously Webstorm/IntelliJ recognized the properties as something that should not be exported.

```
export class someOne {
  constructor(param) {
    this._test = param;
  }

  useTest(){
    return this._test;
  }
}


console.log(new someOne(123).useTest());
```

Comment: Douglas Crockford will not like this solution :). At the end the _test is just accessible, so it's not a private member at all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359724/variable-naming-conventions-other-than-trailing-underscore

Answer (score 7):

Webstorm just tries to prevent you adding unspecified attributes. You need to define getters/setters. This prevents adding and grabbing attributes as dirty hacks.

*Update - added WeakMap to have variables really private.*

```
let testWeakMap = new WeakMap();
export class someOne {
    constructor(param) {
        this.test = param;
    }

    useTest(){
        return this.test;
    }

    get test () {
        return testWeakMap.get(this);
    }

    set test (value) {
        testWeakMap.set(this, value);
    }
}
console.log(new someOne(123).useTest());
```

Comment: So what is proper way to make this warning go away?

Comment: To simply suppress the warning, you can add //noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable before the property declaration.

Comment: Or, in "Editor" > "Inspections" > "Javascript" > "General" > "Unresolved JavaScript variable" disable "Report undeclared properties as error" (PHPStorm 2016.1)

Answer (score 0):

This is a curious error-message which I suspect is probably caused by some bug(s) in WebStorm.

I have these 2 methods in a class in a .mjs -file:

```
 reports_elementIsNotExported_error ()
 { let abc = bad;
 }

 reports_unresolvedVariableOrType_error ()
 { let abc = bad77;
 }
```

When I run Code -> Inspect Code on this file
the first method reports "**Element is not exported**".

The second one reports "**Unresolved variable of type bad77**"

I looked into my Node.js 'global' and neither 'bad' nor 'bad77' exists as a field of it. Why '**bad**' should produce a different message than '**bad77**' I have no idea.